# Custom serializer in Apache Storm 1.1.0

Tags: serialization, apache-storm, kryo, apache-storm-topology

I use custom serializer in Storm topology config like this :

```
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_FALL_BACK_ON_JAVA_SERIALIZATION, false);
config.registerSerialization(ObjectNode.class, ObjectNodeSerializer.class);
```

ObjectNodeSerializer.class is well instanciated during bolts preparation but serialize and deserialize methods are never called during topology execution.

Answer (score 1):

By default Storm will not serialize any tuple when it passes it to bolts within the same Worker. If you only have a single Worker process (running in local-cluster mode?) and want to test serialization, set following config

`topology.testing.always.try.serialize: true`

Comment: I'm happy to read that this morning ! I was thinking of this possibilty to night and after tests with topology.testing.always.try.serialize property in cluster and local-cluster modes, everything looks logic ! thx